# Convert number to hex

Tags: perl

I use `sprintf` for conversion to hex - example >>

```
$hex = sprintf("0x%x",$d)
```

But I was wondering, if there is some alternative way how to do it without `sprintf`.

My goal is convert a number to 4-byte hex code (e.g. `013f571f`)

Additionally (and optionally), how can I do such conversion, if number is in `4 * %0xxxxxxx` format, using just 7 bits per byte?

Comment: Under what circumstances would you want to convert and not print?

Comment: I could suggest use of `pack` and `unpack`, but I'm not sure "elegant" would be the correct description.

Comment: `unpack` is probably *not* what you want (as alternative to `sprintf`), the numbers are treated as string. For example, `unpack("H*", 50)` returns `3530`

Comment: `sprintf("%08x", $d)` is just fine.

Comment: Not clear on what your second question means. In fact, no clue whatsoever.

Comment: @doubleDown: hence the mention of *pack and* unpack

Comment: there seems to be some confusion; what are you doing with the result here?  do you want a string result "013f571f", or you want a 4-byte long string with the value of the internal numeric storage of the number ("\x01\x3f\x57\x1f" or "\x1f\x57\x3f\x01" depending on if you want little-endian or big-endian internal storage format)

Comment: and what would the output of your 7-bits per byte look like?  can you give an example of input and output?

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf()` is probably the most appropriate way. According to http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html:

> To present something as hex, look into [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html), [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), and [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html).

I'm not really sure about your second question, it sounds like `unpack()` would be useful there.

Comment: I'd like to note [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) as a good guide for using `pack`/`unpack`

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is convert a number to 4-byte hex code (e.g. 013f571f)

Hex is a textual representation of a number. `sprintf '%X'` returns hex (the eight characters `013f571f`). `sprintf` is specifically designed to format numbers into text, so it's a very elegant solution for that.

...But it's not what you want. You're not looking for hex, you're looking for the 4-byte internal storage of an integer. That has nothing to do with hex.

```
pack 'N', 0x013f571f;  # "\x01\x3f\x57\x1f" Big-endian byte order
pack 'V', 0x013f571f;  # "\x1f\x57\x3f\x01" Little-endian byte order
```

Comment: seems possible that's what's wanted, but not certain?

Comment: @ysth, Either he wants hex, in which case he already has a perfectly elegant way of doing it (`sprintf '%08X'`), or he wants a packed integer, for which I've provided the means. Covered either way.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf()` is my usual way of performing this conversion. You can do it with unpack, but it will probably be more effort on your side.

For only working with 4 byte values, the following will work though (maybe not as elegant as expected!):

```
print unpack("H8", pack("N1", $d));
```

Be aware that this will result in 0xFFFFFFFF for numbers bigger than that as well.

For working `pack/unpack` with arbitrary bit length, check out http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=383881

The [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) will be a handy read as well.

Answer (score 1):

For `4 * %0xxxxxxx` format, my non-`sprintf` solution is:

```
print unpack("H8", pack("N1", 
  (((($d>>21)&0x7f)<<24) + ((($d>>14)&0x7f)<<16) + ((($d>>7)&0x7f)<<8) + ($d&0x7f))));
```

Any comments and improvements are very welcome.

Comment: And this is supposed to be more elegant than sprintf?